Creating Node-Specific Tree Diagrams with Pyvis or Alternative Libraries?
I am working on generating hierarchical graphs using Pyvis. In my case, the nodes are not all connected to each other, so I would like to implement a dropdown menu that allows selecting a node by name. Upon selecting a node, a diagram showing only the tree corresponding to that node should be generated. Is it possible to achieve this using Pyvis, or would it be better to use another Python library?
